# How to use a TcpStream in multiple branches of a Tokio future chain?

Tags: asynchronous, tcp, rust, future, rust-tokio

I have a Rust Tokio TCP server. Each client is handled by the Tokio future chain that looks like this:

```
let stream = <TcpStream from elsewhere>;

let task = database_connection
        .and_then(connection| {
            tokio::io::write_all(stream, SomeSuccessData);
        }).map_err(|error| {
            tokio::io::write_all(stream, SomeErrorData(error));
        });

...

tokio::spawn(task);
```

The issue is I cannot use the same `TcpStream` in multiple branches of the chain, because `tokio::io::write_all` consumes the stream, even though it is supposed to be used in sequential manner. It is crucial to send different data depending on if there was, e.g., a database error.

How can I overcome this problem? Maybe there is a different API?

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [`io::write_all`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.12/tokio/io/fn.write_all.html) states:

> Any error which happens during writing will cause both the stream and the buffer to get destroyed.

Since your code appears to be attempting to send a network message to indicate that the previous network message failed (which seems... dubious), the `TcpStream` is already gone by the time you try to send the second message.

The easiest solution is thus to clone the stream:

```
let stream2 = stream.try_clone().expect("Couldn't clone");

let task = database_connection
    .and_then(|_| io::write_all(stream, b"success"))
    .map_err(|_| io::write_all(stream2, b"error"));
```

If you only wanted to try to report the failure of the database connection, it's much easier: use [`Future::then`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.25/futures/future/trait.Future.html#method.then) instead of `and_then`:

```
let task = database_connection.then(|connection| match connection {
    Ok(_) => io::write_all(stream, &b"success"[..]),
    Err(_) => io::write_all(stream2, &b"error"[..]),
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I have already found the `then` combinator and it works perfectly for me!